# Can't correctly receive data in Django from Ajax

Tags: jquery, django, ajax

I wand to receive array data in Django view from jquery/Ajax request but in some reason I cannot correctly do it.
This is the piece of js code:

```
    var arr = [1, 2];
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/go/',
        data: {arr: arr},
        success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success!');
        },
    });
```

And this is from Django view:

```
def go(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    arr = request.POST['arr']
```

It gives me `KeyError: 'arr'`

If I do `print(request.POST)` in Django it prints it like this: `<QueryDict: {'arr[]': ['1', '2']}>`. Some square brackets appear after 'arr' key. Then if I do `arr = request.POST['arr[]']` using the key with square brackets it assings `arr` value `2`, so only the last value of the array. Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the key is `'arr[]'`, since it contains an *array*, so you access this with:

```
def go(request):
  if request.method == 'POST':
    arr = request.POST.getlist('arr[]')
```

You need to use [**`.getlist(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) to retrieve all values, since the different elements are all passed as individual key-value items.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a list, and so will need to use the getlist method to retrieve the data.